# SQL Query returning dates in descending order

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using my phpmyadmin which is linked up to our CRM system where we can pull reports from our DB. I'm trying to return a report where the dates will be in descending order - however my query doesn't seem to be returning the order by command correctly.

Query I have is:

```
SELECT emp.emp_firstname as `first name` 
     , emp.emp_lastname as `last name`
     , emp.emp_work_email as `email` 
     , emp.custom6 as `Agency` 
     , emp.employee_id as `crewcode` 
     , emp.custom67 as `nationality`
     , emp.custom14 as `Salary options`
     , emp.custom15 as `Salary options comments`
     , emp.custom17 as `Salary options date of change`
     , emp.custom30 as `Bank Cert` 
FROM `hs_hr_employee` emp  
WHERE emp.custom61 LIKE "active-oam" 
ORDER by emp.custom17 DESC
```

Comment: What data type in custom17?

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output

Comment: a `LIKE` condition without wildcards doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT emp.emp_firstname as `first name` 
 , emp.emp_lastname as `last name`
 , emp.emp_work_email as `email` 
 , emp.custom6 as `Agency` 
 , emp.employee_id as `crewcode` 
 , emp.custom67 as `nationality`
 , emp.custom14 as `Salary options`
 , emp.custom15 as `Salary options comments`
 , emp.custom17 as `Salary options date of change`
 , emp.custom30 as `Bank Cert` 
  FROM `hs_hr_employee` emp  
  WHERE emp.custom61 LIKE "active-oam" 
  ORDER by emp.custom17 DESC, emp.employee_id DESC
```

Give that a try

Comment: Hi, Thanks that didn't work though! Date is formatted as month/day/year. The employee ID is not numerical

Comment: Which is the primary Key? You can try ordering by that as a secondary to your emp.custom17

Comment: Sorry @Fred was correct - date is set as char or varchar - Any ideas how to convert this??

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

This should help you out :)

Comment: @user2381420 "*Date is formatted as month/day/year.*" that is your problem. **Never** store dates in `varchar` columns. That's why your sorting is wrong. Fix your table and convert `custom17` to a real `DATE` column and give it a proper name during that conversion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your help. We had a developer set it up for us so I don't have access to the DB at the moment. Would something like this work: ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, emp.custom17,110)  DESC